R on Win10: Cyrillic encoding works with exception <U+0473>
After starting a new R session on Win10 with the default Sys.setlocale setting changed to "Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ukrainian")", importing a UTF-8 BOM formatted csv-based data table as data.frame p0 with cyrillic characters runs smoothly without any problems. However, there is one specific Cyrillic character that doesn't "translate" correctly as the cyrillic small letter known as Fita ("ѳ"). The character appears as "<U+0473>" within the string in column "Description". Using a different Sys.setlocale (e.g. "russian") did not solve the problem at all.
Eg. I know that in line 94 of the data.frame p0 in the second column the string should start with the mentioned Fita:
p0[94,1:2]

Then the result of the R-Installation on Win10 looks like
         Date                     Description
94 2023-01-11 <U+0473>(застаріло) Нарахування

The result on MacOSX is correctly using all cyrillic characters:
         Date              Description
94 2023-01-11 ѳ(застаріло) Нарахування

Importing and translating the same original csv file with changing default Sys.setlocale setting via "Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ukrainian")" works on both MacOS and Linux.
But this is not a real solution: Unfortunately, these type of multiple files must be converted and parsed on a Win10-based OS.
Any helpful comments and even solutions to get rid of this strange behaviour are very welcome.
Issue is not reproducable on MacOSX and/or LUNX-based OS.

What if you try Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale=".65001") or  Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale=".utf8")?

@JosefZ Thank you. Unfortunately using the mentioned Sys.setlocale()-settings did not solve the problem.
